# What is the appropriate buffersize to recieve a 2 char string with python socket?

Tags: python, sockets, buffer

I need to send and recieve an 'ok' message with Python Sockets in the default IPv4 net. Is there an appropriate buffer dimension or is It irrilevant?

The Server:

```py
    [...]
    msg = 'ok'
    conn.send(msg.encode())
    [...]
```

The client:

```py
    [...]
    check = str(s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE), 'utf-8')
    [...]
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the `ok`?  If it is in ANSI/UTF-8, you only need 2-3 bytes, depending on if a null-terminator is present.  If it is in UTF-16, you need 4-6 bytes, again depending on the null terminator.  It would help if you would provide more details about the protocol you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've edited the post with the code.